# Excel import data issue

Tags: .net, excel

I am having an issue when importing data from excel to database. If excel nth row having large no data and before nth row , there is small amount of data then all data from nth row column are not getting imported. It is importing only 100-200 char.

Comment: please upload the import code so we can get a better understanding of yoour issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing from Excel to a database and the target table is being created automatically,  then the import wizard looks up the first rows to determine the type and length of the fields.  The problem is that it might underestimate the actual length of some fields or might incorrectly assume incorrect data types. To avoid that, you might want to empty the created table, fix the field lengths and import into the already created table.